# Simple recursive plagiarism detector for arrays

Tags: python, list

I was thinking about a very simple plagiarism detector. For the sake of simplicity, let's say you would have two lists in the beignning, each with some string elements, for example:

```
l1 = [ "I","like","big","yellow","bananas" ]
l2 = [ "I","like","yellow","bananas" ]
```

The user could also specify, how much each operation "costs", let's say:

```
DeletePrice = 10          #deleting word from one list
InsertPrice = 1           #insterting a word to one list
SubstitutePrice = 24      #substituing a word for another one
```

The task is to match the lists and the combined price has to be the lowest possible. There are two obvious ways to match those arrays, one would be to delete the word "big" from the first array ( which would cost 10 ) or to insert a word "big" to the second array ( which would cost 1 ). The answer for the algorithm would be thus 1.

I was thinking that for the beginning we should find the elements, that do not match, by using list comprehention:

```
def Plagiarism( l1,l2,dPrice,iPrice,sPrice ):
    not_matching_elements = [ [ x for x in l1 if x not in l2 ],[ x for x in l2 if x not in l1 ] ]
```

The
  `not_matching_elements`
 list would give us 
    `[ [ big ],[] ]`
and would probably help us to move along. But I can't figure out a way to further develop that algorithm. Thank you.

Comment: So is the question "please finish developing my algorithm?" Also if the first step you took was to find differences wouldn't the next step be to use the differences to calculate the cost?

Comment: This question needs more help than we can provide. We like helping people, but sometimes the person needs to help themselves first by reading a book on the language, the on-line documentation, or asking someone they know who can help them. Once you understand the topic a little better, we invite you to edit this question and get it re-opened.

Comment: More to the point, what's wrong with the plagiarism algorithms you found on line before you posted here?  Where are you stuck in choosing and implementing one of those?  What alternate method did you develop?

Comment: Check out this Python plagiarism checker: https://github.com/architshukla/Plagiarism-Checker. This checker uses ngrams

Comment: @Jacobr365 I am not asking you to finish the code, I was asking for some ideas to help me move with it, because I sort of ran out of ideas. Thank you.

Comment: @FlashDrive well if the operation Delete has lower price defined by the user, then it is better to delete instead of inserting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is really similar to Levenshtein distance:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

You just want array entries instead of characters.

You could simply find a levensthein algorithm and change it to suit your needs

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Python

This algorithm might even work for arrays ;)

EDIT: This works:

```
def levenshtein(s1, s2):
    insertionCost=1
    deletionCost=1
    substitutionCost=1

    if len(s1) < len(s2):
        return levenshtein(s2, s1)

    # len(s1) >= len(s2)
    if len(s2) == 0:
        return min(deletionCost,insertionCost)*len(s1)

    previous_row = range(len(s2) + 1)
    for i, c1 in enumerate(s1):
        current_row = [i + 1]
        for j, c2 in enumerate(s2):
            insertions = previous_row[j + 1] + insertionCost # j+1 instead of j since previous_row and current_row are one character longer
            deletions = current_row[j] + deletionCost       # than s2
            substitutions = previous_row[j] + substitutionCost*(c1 != c2)
            current_row.append(min(insertions, deletions, substitutions))
        previous_row = current_row

    return previous_row[-1]


#returns 2
print(levenshtein(['abc','def','ghi'],['abc','ghi','e']))
```

Comment: @TheTask1337 no Problem ;)